# Should I wait until post-game to read Secret Reports?

Tags: neo-the-world-ends-with-you

While playing through week 3 of *NEO: TWEWY*, I managed to obtain Secret Report No. 3 by accident. Apparently it unlocks after [completing 70% of the Social Network](https://www.thegamer.com/neo-the-world-ends-with-you-secret-report-location-guide/). This surprised me, as Secret Reports in the original TWEWY couldn't be obtained until you beat the main story, as they contained major end-game spoilers.

If I'm looking to avoid spoilers, should I wait until I beat the main story to read Secret Reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend waiting to read the Secret Reports until after you have completed the main story. The Secret Reports directly relate to the game's main story. They reveal things that the game's main story only implies.

Secret Report 3, (and possibly 4 and 6), are the only Secret Reports that can be obtained before completing the game. Every other Secret Report either requires winning a fight that isn't available until after completing the main story, achieving 100% social network completion, or collecting every other Secret Report.

Comment: So ... do they contain spoilers? The fact that most aren't obtainable until after the main story is complete isn't really relevant if their content is benign or otherwise supplemental.

Comment: The Secret Reports directly relate to the game's main story. They reveal things that the game's main story only implies, making it hard to say if it's a "spoiler" per say.